# How to fix dbWriteTable "Error: Can't unquote dbo.test_cars" using Impala connection on backend?

Tags: r, dplyr, odbc, rodbc, r-dbi

I'm trying to write a table in one my databases using dbWriteTable but have been running into a variety of problems. It may be due to the schema or the backend connection to Impala I'm not entirely sure.

I've tried several variations of the dbWriteTable command trying to create a new table called test cars from the mtcars dataset in the dbo database but none have worked. Surprisingly though I am able to use dbCreateTable successfully to create an empty table with column names from my dataset. See what I've tried below:

```r
library(odbc)
library(implyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

impala_con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                        Driver = "impala", 
                        Host = "host",
                        Port = "21050")

#impala_con
#<OdbcConnection> User@Impala
# Database: IMPALA
# Impala Version: 2.11.0-cdh5.14.0


> table_id = DBI::Id(schema = "dbo", name = "test_cars")

> dbWriteTable(  impala_con, name=table_id, as.data.frame(data(mtcars)))
Error: Can't unquote `dbo`.`test_cars`

> dbWriteTable(  impala_con, name=SQL("dbo.test_cars"), as.data.frame(data(mtcars)))
Error: Can't unquote dbo.test_cars


> dbWriteTable(  impala_con, name="dbo.test_cars", mtcars)
Error: <SQL> 'CREATE TABLE `dbo.test_cars` (
  `row_names` STRING,
  `mpg` DOUBLE,
  `cyl` DOUBLE,
  `disp` DOUBLE,
  `hp` DOUBLE,
  `drat` DOUBLE,
  `wt` DOUBLE,
  `qsec` DOUBLE,
  `vs` DOUBLE,
  `am` DOUBLE,
  `gear` DOUBLE,
  `carb` DOUBLE
)
'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (360) Syntax error occurred during query execution: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Invalid table/view name: dbo.test_cars

#The following command creates an empty table with the appropriate columns.

> dbCreateTable(  impala_con, SQL("dbo.test_cars"), mtcars)

#There are multiple databases in the system
#Was able to switch to appropriate database and now getting a different error

#As suggested switch database first and then try dbWriteTable

> dbSendQuery(impala_con, paste("use dbo"))
<OdbcResult>
  SQL  use dbo
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
       Changed: 0

> dbWriteTable(impala_con, name="test_cars", mtcars, overwrite=TRUE)
Error: <SQL> 'INSERT INTO `test_cars` (`row_names`, `mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, `vs`, `am`, `gear`, `carb`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (360) Syntax error occurred during query execution: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 2:
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ^
Encountered: Unexpected character
Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

In addition: Warning message:
In new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : Cancelling previous query

> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Ideally I would like write my dataset from R into my database using the dbWriteTable command to write a table into the database dbo with the table name test_car.

Comment: Quick look in [docs](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/impala_identifiers.html), Impala may not support schemas only database and objects (tables/views/functions). Your connection should be to the named database, `dbo`, so no need to period qualify the *dbname* identifier. Simply run: `dbWriteTable(impala_con, name="test_cars", as.data.frame(data(mtcars)))`

Comment: I tried following your advice with some  moderate success however still unable to write table with r dataframe even though not empty (see above edits)

Comment: That's an interesting error as it appears the parameter placeholder, `?`, is not recognized. Possibly this is due to ODBC driver or DBI. Consider adding a ticket to [r-dbi/odbc issues](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues).

Comment: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/276